# Can't fetch data from Flickr API - CORS error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flickr

I am working on a simple react app, where I get a list of photos using the Flickr API.

```
export default class PhotoApp extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        photoList: []
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getPhotoList()
}

getPhotoList = () => {
    console.log('ya got me!')
    axios.get('https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=safe&format=json&nojsoncallback=true')
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(response.status);
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className='appContainer'>
            <h1>Welcome to my gallery!</h1>
            <PhotoList />
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

The thing is, I get the CORS error when I try to get something and the following error is shown:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=safe&format=json&nojsoncallback=true' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I can't get my head around this problem. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: By the way is it working if you install and enable cors plugin in chrome - "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en. "Although this is not the solution.

Comment: I have installed that and it didn't work, for some reason :S @Ansuman

Comment: You need to get api-key and add your domain to the app list.

Comment: okay going to check that out @BahriCanKarakoyun